# Google Recaptcha v2 - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, recaptcha

Recaptcha v2 has stopped working across my sites, returning a 500 server error.

I've tried rejigging the code in case its an issue at my end but to no avail.

Can anyone see an issue with the below?  All help appreciated

FORM

```
<form id="the_form" action="theprocess.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="demoinput" id="demoinput">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Postit">
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>      
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mysitekey"></div>
</form>
```

PROCESS

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
          $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        }

    $secretKey = "mysecretkey";
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
    $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
        if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
          echo '<h2>You are spammer !</h2>';
        } else {
          echo '<h2>Thanks for posting comment.</h2>';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: 500 is an internal srever error, look into your logfiles and see what is happening

Comment: I have confirmed with my hosts that is indeed a server error. I appreciate your response thank you